# send_keys doesn't send enter after input text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to learn Selenium webdriver using Python. My code for test case looks:

```
 import unittest

#import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


class FindRouteToBerlin(unittest.TestCase):
    # Start Firefox
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_find_route_to_berlin(self):
        driver = self.driver
        # Open HERE Maps
        driver.get('http://wego.here.com')
        self.assertIn("HERE WeGo", driver.title)
        # Go to Search field and fill with city
        search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchbar"]/div/div/input')
        search.send_keys('Berlin')
        search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        # Press "Arrow"
        arrow = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button')))
        arrow.click()
        # Enter address
        address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itinerary_item_input_0"]')
        address.send_keys('Szczecin')
        address.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        """actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(address)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        actions.perform()"""

    #def tearDown(self):
     #   self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

First step with filling text "Berlin" and works without any problem. But when the second step comes it looks like `Keys.RETURN` is not executed after input "Szczecin".

I was trying to solve this problem with some `ActionChains` but after `.perform()` I have error and I've read that those problems are related to bugs in Selenium/Mozilla.

My code for ActionChains was:

```
   actions = ActionChains(driver)
   actions.move_to_element(address)
   actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
   actions.perform()
```

> Error: Message: POST
>   /session/1caed99c-1577-4f1d-804b-4ee397d8750b/moveto did not match a
>   known command

Any suggestions how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: try using send_keys(u'\ue007') instead of RETURN

Comment: @MarcvT I've tried also with send_keys(u'\ue007') but behavior is the same. It only expands list with tips for destination (with send_keys(Keys.RETURN) behavior is the same). I've also tried with send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: `Actions` is still not implemented in `Marionette`. If you need to use `ActionChains`, try `chromedriver` or replace `ActionChains` code lines with similar code

Comment: @Andersson, I've replaced code for ActionChains as you can see by: `address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itinerary_item_input_0"]')
        address.send_keys('Szczecin')
        address.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`
But it doesn't work.

Comment: @bMh, why you want to use `Keys.RETURN`? what exactly you want to do? confirm target city selection?

Comment: @Andersson, yes I want to confirm city. When I do this manualy and write city and push enter route is calculated and I want do the same but via automation test

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select first element from drop-down suggestions instead of using `Keys.RETURN`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itinerary_item_input_0"]')
address.send_keys('Szczecin')
first_suggestion = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'dropdown_list_item')]")))
first_suggestion.click()
```

Comment: Problem is that after my command `address.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` dropdown list is expanded. But when I add something after that it stays hidden.

Code I've added after last send key was something like: `select_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="itinerary_item_1"]/div[2]/div[1]')))
        select_element.click()`

Comment: Drop-down appears just after you send city name to input field- there is no need to use `Return`

Comment: Drop-down appears when I try execute this manualy. In my script this list is shown only when script finish every steps (but send_key doesn't execute ENTER) and I think this is the case why send_keys doesn't work correct in this situation.

Comment: hm.. I still can't get your point. I can select required value from drop-down with my code. I don't use `Enter` key

Comment: My code looks now: `navigate_to = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itinerary_item_input_1"]')
        navigate_to.send_keys('Warszawa')
        first_suggestion = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itinerary_item_1"]/div[2]/div[1]')
        first_suggestion.click()` And when I try to run this test I have: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="itinerary_item_1"]/div[2]/div[1]

Comment: And why do you use this `XPath` `//*[@id="itinerary_item_1"]/div[2]/div[1]` instead of my `"//div[contains(@class, 'dropdown_list_item')]"`?

Comment: When I use you XPath I have `Unable to locate element: //div[contains(@dlass, 'dropdown_list_item')]`

Comment: There is typo in your `XPath`: note that you use `@dlass` instead of `@class`

Comment: My bad during copy&paste. Log from error: `Unable to locate element: //div[contains(@class, 'dropdown_list_item')]`

Comment: I updated answer with `Explicitwait`. Check it and let me know if exception still persist

Comment: Still got `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` I have no idea what I have to do

Answer (score 0):

Following is working for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

def setUp():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.maximize_window()

    driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    base_url = ('enter your url')

    driver.get(base_url)

    task = driver.find_element_by_id("some_element_id")

    task.send_keys("Some_text",Keys.ENTER)


setUp()
```